# How save binary data in SQL Server with PEAR

Tags: php, pear

How do I do an insert into an SQL 'Image' field using the PEAR DB library and sql like this:

```
insert into MyTable (myBlob) values (BlobData)
```

where BlobData is obtained using file_get_contents and looks like this:

```
"BMN\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x06\x0\x0\x0(\x0\x0\x0\x2\x0\x0\x0\x3\x0\x0\x0\x1\x0\x18\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x18\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0ÿÿÿÿÿÿ\x0\x0\x0\x0ÿÿÿÿ\x0\x0ÿÿÿÿÿÿ\x0\x0"
```

I get syntax errors, guessing I need to escape the data somehow. Php code:

```
$data = file_get_contents('c:\\temp\\test.bmp');
$sql = "insert into MyTable (myBlob) values ('".$data."'); //just using inline sql for now to get it working
$db->query($sql);
```

Comment: please show your PHP code

Comment: I edited to show my code

Comment: for storing binary files like images you should use another storage, for example - MogileFS. It's more better, than select field from db. Besides, web servers is pretty to cache images

Comment: Have you tried escaping the contents of the binary file before you try executing it?

Comment: I have to use the SQL 'Image' datatype due to legacy code reasons.

Comment: Escaping like this: "BMN\\x0\\x0..."   then my sql does not crash with the syntax error but the data is corrupted when I try to view the file. I suspect that I need the data in some other format to be used with the 'Image' datatype in SQL Sever?

Answer (score 1):

I found that using bin2hex and writing the binary data as a hex string works:

```
$FileDataBin = file_get_contents($myFile);
$FileDataHex = '0x'.bin2hex($FileDataBin);

$qry = 'update MyTable set SomeBinaryField = '.$FileDataHex.' where SomeOtherField=?';
$DB->query($qry, array('some data'));
```

Note the '0x' prefix and that there are no quotes around the data.